# Combining similiar data frames(similarity given by length) within a list with rbind

Tags: r

I've got a list of data frames with different length each (there are only four different lengths, the example has 3). What I want to do is rbind data frames that have the same length to obtain four bigger data frames as final result.

What I tried is to write a loop that checks takes a data frame "i" from the list, then checks all other data frames "j" but the "i-th" data frame from my list and performs rbind if they have the same length (and saves the output). I believe the problem in my loop is that many times the same data frame is just duplicated and combined (like rbind(df1,df1) but I can't figure out why or how to fix it.

```
#create list of dataframes
df1 <- data.frame("Var1" = c(1:10))
df2 <- data.frame("Var1" = c(1:10),"Var2" = c(1:10))
df3 <- data.frame("Var1" = c(1:10),"Var2" = c(1:10),"Var3" = c(1:10))
df4 <- data.frame("Var1" = c(11:20))
df5 <- data.frame("Var1" = c(11:20),"Var2" = c(11:20),"Var3" = c(11:20))
df.list <- list("df2" = df2,"df1" = df1, "df3" = df3, "df4" = df4, "df5" = df5)

#write the loop
df.list2 <- list()
for (i in seq_along(df.list)){
  for (j in 3:length(df.list)-1){
    if(length(df.list[[i]]) == length(df.list[[j]])){
      df.list2[[i]] <- rbind(df.list[[i]],df.list[[j]])
    } 
  }
}


#this is what it SHOULD look like (example for df1 and df4 (which both have length 1)
df.list3 <- list()
df.list3[[1]] <- rbind(df.list[[2]],df.list[[4]])
df.list3[[1]]

   Var1
1     1
2     2
3     3
4     4
5     5
6     6
7     7
8     8
9     9
10   10
11   11
12   12
13   13
14   14
15   15
16   16
17   17
18   18
19   19
20   20
```

I realized that using this methods unavoidably duplicates are going to show up and so far I play removing them with unique later on.

If there is a better method to resolve this I'm open for it of course, doesn't need to be a loop. But this was as close as I can get.

So ideally in the example I should be left with 3 data frames after removing duplicates, which are:

```
rbind(df1,d4)   #length 1
df2             #length 2
rbind(df3,df5)  #length 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We `split` the 'df.list' by a vector of the number of columns in each of the data.frame in the `list` (`sapply(df.list, ncol)`) and then `rbind` the `split`ted data.frames together.

```
lapply(split(df.list, sapply(df.list, ncol)), function(x) do.call(rbind, x))
```

---

A faster option would be using `rbindlist` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
lapply(split(df.list, sapply(df.list, ncol)), rbindlist)
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked like a charm! Absolutely genius. It's incredible what people who are good at R can achieve in simple ways while you struggle hard to perform tasks which you would consider easy.